# Achieving vertical spacing between element with display table-row?

Tags: css

I need to centre a div. This div is the width of its 2 containing 'rows'. The width of these 'rows' is defined by their content. The content has both left and right aligned elements. I also need the content which is less tall to be vertically centred.

So far Ive done all of this. I also need a background colour on the rows and a space between them. Ive done the space with div.spacer but im wondering if its possible to achieve the same thing without an empty div to keep my markup cleaner?

Im struggling as display table-row and table-cell don't allow for margin.

I also tried using pseudo content to absolutely position a white block over the top to make it look like there was a space between the rows, but relative display doesnt apply well to an element with display table-row cross browser.

I tried using the border-spacing css property but it adds margin both above and below rows, and I just need the margin below.

Below is my markup. The image shows exactly what I need to achieve, so can I do the same thing without div.spacer?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWMPgB

[image]

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Longer Heading</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: grey;
}
h2 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 3em;
}
ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.spacer {
    display: table-row;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
.row > * {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
```

This will add 5px space after your rows.